# Differenza fra 'cazzaro' e 'fancazzista'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, nouns

Sento frequentemente parlare di 'cazzari' e 'fancazzisti', ma non riesco a capire la differenza.

C'è qualcuno che sa spiegare? Inoltre, secondo voi, sono ormai parole che possono essere usate correntemente come 'stupido', 'idiota', 'imbecille' e così via? Oppure è consigliato evitarle e usare dei sinonimi?

Comment: Kyriakos, per favore, usa i tags correttamente.

Comment: "Cazzaro" è termine eminentemente romanesco (e zone limitrofe): da noi in Maremma una persona che spara, per l'appunto, cazzate viene definita talvolta "gassaio", con riferimento al gas di cui si è enfiato per apparire quello che non è, oppure non lo si appella in alcun modo e viene ignorato o mandato sbrigativamente a quel paese.
"Fancazzista", che sembra essere termine usato un po' dappertutto, anche in letteratura (vedi Stefano Benni nel romanzo "Saltatempo") da noi non ha sfondato, dato che da tempo immemorabile una persona che non ha voglia di fare niente viene definita "Leggèra", con evi

Comment: @user2780: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE! Il tuo post non risponde alla domanda dall'OP e per questa ragione è stato convertito in un commento.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Cazzaro* è una persona che dice *cazzate*, cioè bugie e frottole.
*Fancazzista* è chi *non fa un cazzo*, che è un modo volgare di dire *non fa niente* (nel senso di: non è attivo, non lavora, non svolge nessuna attività).

> Sono parole che possono essere usate comunemente come 'stupido', 'idiota', 'imbecille' e così via?

No. *Stupido* è una parola "poco" volgare, che si può pronunciare anche in presenza di bambini. *Idiota*, *imbecille*, *cazzaro* e *fancazzista* hanno un tono molto più volgare e offensivo.
Inoltre, c'è una differenza di registro tra questi termini: delle tre, *stupido* è una parola che si potrebbe sentire (anche se raramente) in un telegiornale e in altre comunicazioni dello stesso registro. Invece *imbecille*, *cazzaro* e *fancazzista* si trovano solo nella lingua parlata popolare.

Inoltre, questa è la prima volta che incontro la parola *cazzaro* (sarà perchè vivo al Nord?). Nel linguaggio popolare non ho mai sentito parlare di *cazzaro*; invece, *fancazzista* è di uso piuttosto comune.

Comment: Idiota ed imbecille sono di registro diverso da cazzaro e fancazzista: è vero che sono insulti abbastanza gravi (se detti seriamente), ma non sono volgari. Viceversa, cazzaro e fancazzista sono insulti leggeri, ma il registro è abbastanza scurrile.

Comment: Non hai mai incontrato la parola "cazzaro" al nord? Giusto per statistica, qual'è la forchetta di età e la provenienza delle persone con le quali normalmente conversi? Non saprei dire da dove provenga, ma a Milano lo uso piuttosto regolarmente, con persone di età variabili fra i 18 e i 50 anni.

Comment: @FedericoBonelli - Visto che siamo specificamente in un sito sulla lingua italiana: “qual è”, non *“qual'è”.

Comment: @DaG colpa mia, credevo fosse un'elisione ed invece apparentemente è un troncamento. Posterò una domanda su questo.

Comment: A me, che sono di Pavia, ''cazzaro'' suona come una parola di Roma. La usiamo spesso ma con la consapevolezza che non è un'espressione di qua.

Comment: anche per me "cazzaro" è una parola dall'aria romanesca, anche se la si usa tranquillamente a Milano.

Comment: Da quello che so "cazzaro" si utilizza in Italia centrale (Roma) e meridionale (viene usato da Caparezza in una sua canzone). Non sono molto d'accordo però con la traduzione in "bugiardo". Secondo me significa non solo uno che racconta falsità, ma anche che in realtà è un buono a nulla.

Answer (score 8):

Cazzaro si dice di colui che dice abitualmente cazzate, cioè falsità. Sinonimi possibili sono il bugiardo, o il conta frottole.

Fancazzista si dice di colui che abitualmente (non) fa un cazzo, cioè un fannullone.

Sono neologismi scurrili, e come tali non andrebbero mai usati, anche se nel linguaggio giovanile sono comunemente usati ed accettati, e si considerano offese lievi.

Answer (score 5):

Per curiosità, l'impagabile *Scrostati gaggio! Dizionario storico dei linguaggi giovanili* di Renzo Ambrogio e Giovanni Casalegno (Utet, 2004) definisce “cazzaro” come «Spaccone, fanfarone o anche chi ama cazzeggiare, scioperato» citandone vari esempi nella narrativa recente, tra cui Giuseppe Borgia ed Enrico Brizzi. “Fancazzista” è dato come «Chi non fa nulla, chi non ha voglia di fare nulla», con esempi da Alessandra Montrucchio e Luciano De Crescenzo.

Confermo le altre risposte, quando dicono che sono senz'altro due termini di registro piuttosto “basso”, da usare con cautela (e magari per niente se non ci si ha familiarità) e che, come ipotizzato in una delle risposte, “cazzaro” si sente soprattutto in Italia centrale (e lo denuncia anche la desinenza).

Comment: Io infatti per "cazzaro" intendo una persona non ha voglia di fare nulla ed è superficiale. Non lo intendo come "uno che racconta bugie".